# What's this white matter in a sauerkraut jar?

Tags: food-safety, fermentation, sauerkraut

I have just opened a jar of store-bought organic raw sauerkraut and I found this white matter on it that you can see in the picture. It doesn't look like regular mold, and it doesn't look like Kahm yeast (from pictures of Kahm yeast I can see on forums at least). I am not sure what it is. [image: sauerkraut]

The description on the jar says "Our raw sauerkrauts are fermented for 4 weeks", if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

White biofilms or sediment are quite common in lactofermented vegetables.  It is simply a byproduct of the lactic acid bacteria and yeasts.  Often you'll see it settle to the bottom. It is not typically a safety hazard, just what happens in lacto-ferments. Hard to tell from your pic.  It almost looks like there was flour or some other white substance on your fork or spoon when you dipped it in.

Comment: It almost looks like there was yogurt on my fork, but in fact the fork was perfectly clean. It's hard to see from the picture (damn me when I bought a phone without macro lens), but the white matter looks wet (like yogurt), not dry (like flour).

Comment: I would suggest a natural, and perfectly fine, occurrence.